# Storing entire code inside the action button

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, action-button

I want to put my whole code inside the action button. As i click the button my whole code dashboard should be visible in my screen(which i am getting right now in my code)
But firstly i must be able to see only that button.

Here is the sample dashboard which i am trying to put in my button.
I have not make the button in this code as this is quite straight forward.Can somebody help please?

```
     library(shinydashboard)

 ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

       box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
   hist(data)
  })
   }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req` in outputs, for e.g.:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$button)
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
   hist(data)
  })
```

Then the output will only be shown if the input is being used.

You can also put things in `conditionalPanel()`. You can use that in the UI part of the script. For example:

```
fluidRow(conditionalPanel(condition = "input.button == true",
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

       box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
)
```

Note that the condition is in javascript.

I've given your button a name and made it TRUE/FALSE but you would need to adapt that depending on the input button.